# jQuery File Upload SELECT in mysql by gallery ID

Tags: php, jquery, pdo, jquery-file-upload

I would like a help with jQuery File Upload, I'm sorry if my English is not correctI would like to show the images by passing an ID parameter through the url or some hidden field because I have a gallery and each gallery has its images.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <!-- estava assim action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/"-->
        <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/UploadHandler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
            <noscript>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/">
            </noscript>
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <!--the hidden input is used to get id by GET in the parameter to urledit= -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="urledit" value="<?php echo $urledit; ?>">
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        <span>Add fotos...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Iniciar upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancelar upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Apagar</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                    <!-- The global file processing state -->
                    <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress state -->
                <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Database class:

```
<?php 
include_once 'config.php';

class conn extends config
{

var $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {
      $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->database, $this->user, $this->pass);

    }

    function getImages($urledit)
    {
        //$urledit = '9';
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT gallery_img FROM site_gallery WHERE gallery_galeria_id = '$urledit'");      
        $run = $stm->execute();

        $array = array();
        while ($rs = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($array,$rs['gallery_img']);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    function deleteImages($foto)
    {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM site_gallery WHERE gallery_img = :foto");
        $stm->bindValue(":foto",$foto);
        $run = $stm->execute();     
    }

    function insertImages($id,$foto,$data)
    {
        try{
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO site_gallery (gallery_galeria_id, gallery_img, gallery_data) VALUES (:id,:foto,:data)");
            $stm->bindValue("id",$id);
            $stm->bindValue("foto",$foto);
            $stm->bindValue("data",$data);
            $run = $stm->execute(); 
            //echo $stm->rowCount();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

UploadHandler.php
to insert into the database works

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = new \stdClass();
    $file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index, $content_range);
    $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)$size);
    $file->type = $type;
    if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
        $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
        $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
            mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
        }
        $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
        $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
            $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
            if ($append_file) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                //insere no banco
                $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $urledit = $this->get_url_edit('urledit');
                $conn = new conn();
                $conn->insertImages($urledit,$file->name,$data);
                $conn->getImages($urledit);
            }
        } else {
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents(
                $file_path,
                fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
            );
        }
```

but this select does not work:

```
protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
    $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
        return array();
    }
    $urledit = $this->get_url_edit('urledit');
    //$urledit = '9';
    $conn = new conn();
    $Images = $conn->getImages($urledit);

    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        array($this, $iteration_method),
        //scandir($upload_dir)
        $Images
    )));
}
```

because it has no value for $Images = $conn->getImages($urledit);

can anybody help me?
Alguém poderia me ajudar? pode ser em português também.

Comment: You're moving the uploaded file to `$file_path`, but you're putting `$file->name` in the database.

Comment: This is wrong: `file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );` it should be `file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    file_get_contents($uploaded_file),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar, Yes I am sending the files to a folder and then write the name of the files in the database. Here the insert part works. The problem is that I want to show these files according to the ID that will be in the URL.

Comment: It seems like you need a method `getImage()` that takes an ID and just looks up that image.

Comment: so I have these two methods in the UploadHandler.php:  protected function get_url_edit($urledit) {
        return @$_POST[$urledit];
    }
    protected function get_urledit_by_get($id) {
        return @$_GET[$id];
    }
The POST is in a hidden input in index.php to send the ID to the insertImages function ($id, $photo, $data) 
and this GET that does not get the id of the url that should pass to the getImages() in the conn.php

Comment: Does `$this->get_url_edit('urledit')` returns the ID that was requested? If not, you need another method that does that.

Comment: Then I don't see why `get_file_objects()` isn't doing what you want. Does `var_dump($Images)` show the correct result?

Comment: yes `$this->get_url_edit('urledit') returns the ID only for the insert method.`
I could solve here by creating a new method and passing a session with the id and worked.

Comment: Just use `$_GET['id']` to get the ID for the GET method.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, the only way was `session_start();
$_SESSION['idurl'] = $_GET['urledit'];` and in the file UploadHandler.php        `$urledit = $_SESSION['idurl'];
        $conn = new conn();
        $Images = $conn->getImages($urledit);`

Comment: thanks @Barmar for your help! 
for now it's the way I want it, I'll make some more changes